# Why would findOne($query) work on a collection and find($query) not using PHP's Mongo driver?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using PHP to talk with a Mongo use `findOne($query)` on a `db.collection` it returns a result as I would expect. But changing that command to find() returns nothing.

From the shell, if you use db.collection.find() it returns all documents. Can anyone explain why the PHP driver's `find()` wouldn't return results even when `findOne()` does while using the exact same query?

UPDATE: Here's the code.

`find()` (doesn't work):

```
  $db = $connection->selectDB( $database );
  $returned_collection = $db->selectCollection( $collection );
  $cursor = $returned_collection->find( $query );
```

);

`find()` debug output:

```
query: array(1) {
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(13) "4d03d13b71676"
}
1292099894 > mongo_wrapper.class.php > returned_collection: events.votes 
db: object(MongoDB)#41 (2) {
  ["w"]=>
  int(1)
  ["wtimeout"]=>
  int(10000)
}
cursor: object(MongoCursor)#43 (0) {
}
```

`findOne()` (works):

```
  $db = $connection->selectDB( $database );
  $returned_collection = $db->selectCollection( $collection );
  $cursor = $returned_collection->findOne( $query );
```

`findOne()` debug output:

```
query: array(1) {
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(13) "4d03d13b71676"
}
1292099906 > mongo_wrapper.class.php > returned_collection: events.votes 
db: object(MongoDB)#7862 (2) {
  ["w"]=>
  int(1)
  ["wtimeout"]=>
  int(10000)
}
cursor: array(7) {
  ["_id"]=>
  object(MongoId)#7849 (1) {
    ["$id"]=>
    string(24) "4d03d842d0645afaab4e92f6"
  }
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(13) "4d03d13b71676"
  ["timestamp"]=>
  int(1292095809)
  ["context"]=>
  string(3) "ms3"
  ["uri"]=>
  string(120) "http://feeds.marketwatch.com/~r/marketwatch/podcasts/MarketwatchStupidInvestmentOfTheWeek/~3/3H-tMQLS9AA/siotw103009.mp3"
  ["type"]=>
  string(8) "category"
  ["vote"]=>
  int(-1)
}
```

Both use this debug code:

```
    if($debug->enabled) {
        echo time() . " > mongo_wrapper.class.php > returned_collection: $returned_collection \n";
        if($debug->dump) {
            echo "db: ";
            var_dump( $db );
            echo "cursor: ";
            var_dump( $cursor );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just checking... you're not trying to access the results of find as an object are you? Because `find` returns and array and `findOne` returns an entity object.

Comment: Good question. Tried both ways, and no results either way.

Comment: Could you show us your PHP and query in your question above?

Comment: I've updated the question with this. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: @rojoca you know, you're right. `vardump()` ing the result didn't work but it appears that using `iterator_to_array()` will indeed pull in the data. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

$connection = new Mongo();

$db = $connection->database;

$collection = $db->collection;

echo '<pre>';

print_r($collection->findOne());

$cursor = $collection->find();
foreach ($cursor as $id => $value) {
    echo "$id: ";
    print_r($value);
}

echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Comment: A man of few words, but thanks for the clarification - explains OP's troubles (as well as my frustrations today).